# Sending data to server using WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, networking, webrtc

I'd like to use RTCDataChannel to establish a communication link between the browser and server, and communicate data.

Since I know the ip and port of the server already, I assume I don't need a signaling server.

My server is listening on port 8000 (localhost) for incoming UDP packets, I'd like to be able to send a simple 'hello' message to the server from the browser using RTCDataChannel, at localhost:8000

This is what I have come up with so far,

```
var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection ||
        window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;

var conn = new RTCPeerConnection(null, {optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]});
conn.createOffer().then(function(desc)
                        {
                            console.log('offer: ', desc);
                            console.log(desc.sdp);
                            var sdp =
                            "v=0\n" +
                            "o=- 3796159382343068508 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\n" +
                            "s=-\n"+
                            "t=0 0\n"+
                            "a=msid-semantic: WMS\n"+
                            "m=application 8000 DTLS/SCTP 8000\n" +
                            "c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\n"+
                            "b=AS:30\n"+
                            "a=ice-ufrag:35DwSa/DJYutqkxx\n" +
                            "a=ice-pwd:SidH+lMhnJt/SSLZlbPjANGw\n"+
                            "a=fingerprint:sha-256 A2:4B:24:23:4D:C9:2B:68:35:9B:30:7B:44:C9:11:91:35:07:49:67:24:F0:14:84:58:EA:1B:F1:72:B9:89:24\n"
                            +"a=setup:active\n"+
                            "a=mid:data\n"+
                            "a=sctpmap:8000 webrtc-datachannel 8000\n";

                            console.log("Final sdp: ", sdp);

                            desc.sdp = sdp;



                            conn.setRemoteDescription(desc, function(result)
                            {
                                console.log("Success", result);
                                chan = conn.createDataChannel("sendDataChannel", {reliable: false});
                                chan.send("yo");

                            }, function(error)
                            {
                                console.log("Error: " , error);
                            })

                        });
```

I receive the following error in console when I run this:

> Error:  DOMException: Failed to set remote offer sdp: Session error
>   code: ERROR_CONTENT. Session error description: Failed to set remote
>   data description send parameters.

What do I need to change / what am I doing wrong, to get this to work?

Comment: WebRTC isn't just sending arbitrary data via UDP on an IP address. Your server has to support WebRTC. It's an offer/answer for SRTP and DTLS between peers (which can be client server).

Comment: Simply put: what you're trying to do will not work. I'd suggest reading up on WebRTC before going further. http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000545/ch18.html#_real_time_network_transports

Comment: As I commented in your previous question (which you should have used to put this code too), WebRTC is intended for something else.

Comment: @xdumaine I feel like you should be able to support a protocol without having to read a book. Can you tell me what steps I'm missing in order to receive the 'hello' message on server?

Comment: In other words, what does my server need to do exactly? At the moment, I can't even get the js to hit my server at all. So how does the js (browser) know whether or not my server supports it?

Comment: Why don't you just use a websocket?

Comment: I'm not going to give you a lesson in a complex protocol stack. You're not even willing to read about it?

Comment: @xdumaine I'm  happy to read about it, but all the examples pertain to P2P and there don't seem to be any examples about how you can implement the protocol yourself on server. I want to test the performance of UDP vs TCP which is why i want to use this over Websockets

Comment: I wish people would stop trying to implement WebRTC for a simple client-server connection.... sigh..

Comment: [Take a look at this, maybe it works for you](http://www.hacksparrow.com/node-js-udp-server-and-client-example.html)

Comment: @Kevin, actually it seems totally legit to use the "capture of medias" part of webRTC and to do whatever you want with that thereafter.